# Create workspace variables from table

Tags: matlab

Essentially I would like to do the opposite of [create table from workspace variables](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html). I.e. for a table containing `Var1, Var2, ...`, assign `Var1, Var2` into the base environment, or if called from within a function, assign these variables to the calling environment.

For example:

```
load patients    
patients = table(Age,Gender,Height,Weight,Smoker,...
    'RowNames',LastName);
```

Patients has 5 variables, I would like to assign them to the workspace. E.g. do `Age = patients.Age`, `Gender = patients.Gender` ... Is there a way to do this without manually typing everything?

Answer (score 0):

The example given in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) I think should be what you're looking for.  For completeness, I'll create the table to so it can be easily verified:

Create a table:

```
load patients    
patients = table(Age,Gender,Height,Weight,Smoker,...
    'RowNames',LastName);
```

Extract data from a table and assign it to variable `A`:

```
A = patients{1:5,{'Height','Weight'}};
```

A is 5x2 array of the height and weight of patients 1-5, as can be seen from:

```
    whos A;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, sorry I believe my question was not clear enough. Patients has 5 variables, I would like to assign them to the workspace. E.g. do `Age = patients.Age`, `Gender = patients.Gender` ...

Comment: hmmm... is there a reason that this kind of syntax won't work: `Age = patients{:,'Age'}`, etc. ?

Comment: well, I would like to use a function to assign all the variables to the calling environment, manually typing it out is not going to be helpful.

Comment: essentially I am looking for the equivalent of `R`'s `attach` and `with` commands

Comment: and explain why this works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304654/how-does-rowfun-know-to-reference-variables-inside-a-table

Comment: @Alex hmm... I'll take a look tomorrow - maybe someone will post in the meantime.