# How does rowfun know to reference variables inside a table

Tags: matlab

From the [documentation](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rowfun.html), we see the following example:

```
g = gallery('integerdata',3,[15,1],1);
x = gallery('uniformdata',[15,1],9);
y = gallery('uniformdata',[15,1],2);

A = table(g,x,y)

func = @(x, y) (x - y);

B = rowfun(func,A,...
    'GroupingVariable','g',...
    'OutputVariableName','MeanDiff')
```

When the function `func` is applied to `A` in `rowfun` how does it know that there are variables in `A` called `x` and `y`?

*EDIT*: I feel that my last statement must not be true, as you do not get the same result if you did `A = table(g, y, x)`.

I am still very confused by how `rowfun` can use a function that does not actually use any variables defined within the calling environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify the rows (and their order) with the Name/Value argument `InputVariables`, Matlab will simply take column 1 as first input, column 2 as second input etc, ignoring eventual grouping columns.

Consequently, for better readability and maintainability of your code, I consider it good practice to always specify `InputVariables` explicitly.